# How do you convert a selection of text from a webpage into html tags?

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

My current workflow requires me to copy a piece of text from a webpage and extract the html tags. I'm currently doing it by selecting the text, going to [wordtohtml.net](http://wordtohtml.net/), pasting it, and copying the output with the html tags and the correct class information. See below:

[image]

Is there a command line utility that I could pipe the piece of text I initially copied and would do the conversion for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a bookmarklet for you

1. Go to the website and drag the bookmarklet to your Bookmarks bar
2. Select any text on a website
3. Click the bookmarklet
4. Copy the HTML from the textarea
5. Paste the HTML wherever you want

[Get HTML of selection bookmarklet](https://pwny.gorilla.moe/#!/?a=1&s=html&c=4&l=16&t=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)

This is the bookmarklets *Source-Code*:

```
javascript:(function()%7B(function(window%2Cdocument) %7Bvar range%3Bvar calert%3Bcalert %3D function(text)%7Bvar w %3D Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth%2C window.innerWidth %7C%7C 0)%3Bvar h %3D Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight%2C window.innerHeight %7C%7C 0)%3Bvar offset %3D %7Btop%3A ((h %2F 2) %2B window.scrollY - 240)%2Cleft%3A ((w %2F 2) - window.scrollX - 320)%7D%3Bvar container %3D document.createElement('div')%3Bcontainer.style.display %3D 'block'%3Bcontainer.style.border %3D '2px solid %23000'%3Bcontainer.style.borderRadius %3D '10px'%3Bcontainer.style.position %3D 'absolute'%3Bcontainer.style.zIndex %3D 99999999%3Bcontainer.style.backgroundColor %3D '%23fff'%3Bcontainer.style.width %3D '340px'%3Bcontainer.style.padding %3D '10px'%3Bcontainer.style.top %3D offset.top %2B 'px'%3Bcontainer.style.left %3D offset.left %2B 'px'%3Bvar contents %3D document.createElement('textarea')%3Bcontents.style.display %3D 'block'%3Bcontents.style.width %3D '310px'%3Bcontents.style.height %3D '240px'%3Bcontents.style.border %3D '1px solid %23ccc'%3Bcontents.value %3D text%3Bvar button %3D document.createElement('button')%3Bbutton.innerHTML %3D 'Close'%3Bbutton.style.display %3D 'block'%3Bbutton.onclick %3D function(evt)%7Bevt.preventDefault()%3Bthis.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)%3B%7D%3Bcontainer.appendChild(contents)%3Bcontainer.appendChild(button)%3Bdocument.body.appendChild(container)%3B%7D%3Bif (document.selection %26%26 document.selection.createRange) %7Brange %3D document.selection.createRange()%3Breturn range.htmlText%3B%7Delse if (window.getSelection) %7Bvar selection %3D window.getSelection()%3Bif (selection.rangeCount > 0) %7Brange %3D selection.getRangeAt(0)%3Bvar clonedSelection %3D range.cloneContents()%3Bvar div %3D document.createElement('div')%3Bdiv.appendChild(clonedSelection)%3Bcalert(div.innerHTML)%3B%7Delse %7Bcalert('no selection')%3B%7D%7Delse %7Bcalert('no selection')%3B%7D%7D)(window%2Cdocument)%7D)()
```

Comment: Dude, you're awesome! Thank you so much!!